# Imported six module but Python 2 print function is giving error

Tags: python

I am using python 3.10.I have had to use code that was originally written with python 2.7. In order to make it compatible with python 3.10 I am importing `six`. However the `print` function from 2.7 still gives me an error saying `End of statement expected`. My code is as follows:

```
import six
print 'Result OK!'
```

Why is `six` not able to import the print function from python 2.7?
NB:I am using python files written with 2.7, I don't want to update them to 3.10 syntax. I just want to use functions from them without having to update them because they are files I share with other people who at the moment don't want to migrate to python 3, so I am trying to find a walk around to the situation.

Comment: six doesn't magically make invalid syntax valid

Comment: In Python 3, `print` is a function not a statement. In Python 2 you can add a `from __future__ import print_function` and use it as such. There is no way to go the other direction (use Py2 syntax in Py3). This means you *will* have to update the files, but you can do so in a way that will work in both versions of the language.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print in python 3 you need to use parenthesis around the print statement like :

```
print('Result OK!')
```

Also to print you don't need to import anything :)

Comment: NB:I am using python files written with 2.7,i don't want to update them to 3.10 syntax.I just want to use functions from them without having to update them because they are files I share with other people that at the moment don't want to migrate to python 3.so am trying to find a walk around to the situation.

Comment: `print("Foo")` is still valid Python 2.7 syntax. If you want to run it on Python 3, it needs to have Python 3 syntax. Look at using python-future if your collaborators are looking to stay on Python 2 for now.

Comment: In Python 3, `print` is a *function* not a statement — i.e. there is no `print` statement in Python 3.

Comment: yes but i thought that by importing six then the print statement would become valid in in Python 3 since it's meant to allow for the compatibility of python 2 and python 3.